# Create a new Surface type with SDL_Texture

Tags: sdl2, pixel, awesomium

So I started using Awesomium, and I'm experiencing some difficulties.

I want to create a new type of `Awesomium::Surface` and implement it in my custom `Awesomium::SurfaceFactory` to render `Awesomium::WebView->surface` as `SDL_Texture`.

I'm currently stuck at the [Paint function](http://www.awesomium.com/docs/1_7_2/cpp_api/class_awesomium_1_1_surface.html#ac69c2b325f3068ff4a356307b882de9c) which is supposed to update some pixels, so I have this (in the project it's separated in header and definitions):

```
class AwsSurface {

    public:
    AwsSurface(int w, int h) : public Awesomium::Surface {
        // _renderer is my global renderer, on Awesomium DOCs it says that pixels are
        // "in 32-bit BGRA format" so I guess the format is right...
        texture = SDL_CreateTexture(
            _renderer, 
            SDL_PIXELFORMAT_BGRA8888, 
            SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING, 
            w, 
            h
        );
        dst_rect = {0, 0, w, h};        
    }

    void Paint(unsigned char* src_buffer, 
             int src_row_span, 
             const Awesomium::Rect &src_rect, 
             const Awesomium::Rect &dest_rect) {
    }

    protected:
    SDL_Texture* texture;
    SDL_Rect dst_rect;
};
```

I'm not sure if I get it right, but from[what the DOCs say](http://www.awesomium.com/docs/1_7_2/cpp_api/class_awesomium_1_1_surface.html#ac69c2b325f3068ff4a356307b882de9c) if I'm given a `src_rect={2, 1, 2, 3}` and `src_row_span=20` I am in this situation, right?

[image]

Now, I understood how the buffer works (more or less), but I don't know how to copy the pixels from it onto my texture (in the given position).

**Edit:** I came up with this paint function:

```
void AwsSurface::Paint(unsigned char* src_buffer, 
                       int src_row_span, 
                       const aws::Rect &src_rect, 
                       const aws::Rect &dest_rect) {
    Uint32* src_buffer_i = (Uint32*)src_buffer;
    src_row_span /= 4;
    int dest_row_span;
    Uint32* dest_buffer;
    SDL_Rect r = AwsRectToSDL(dest_rect); // Custom function to convert the rect
    SDL_LockTexture(
        texture, 
        &r, 
        (void**)&dest_buffer, 
        &dest_row_span
    );
    dest_row_span /= 4;
    for (int x = 0; x < src_rect.width; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < src_rect.height; y++) {
            Uint32* s = src_buffer_i + (src_rect.y + y) * src_row_span + src_rect.x + x;
            Uint32* d = dest_buffer + (dest_rect.y + y) * dest_row_span + dest_rect.x + x;
            *d = *s; // Here happens the exception
        }
    }
    SDL_UnlockTexture(texture);
}
```

But I get an **"access violation on writing"** exception on the line above, this happens after some successful executions *(usually 6/7)* and every time on the same rectangle `{0, 0, 466, 26}`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30626543

Comment: @Tyyppi_77 That question has an answer only for surfaces, I'm looking for textures

Comment: Downvoters, care to explain?

Comment: Where is the access violation? What line? If you just memset the texture with the correct size calculation, say to 0xFF, does the problem happen still? Worth trying to isolate where the violation is from.

Comment: @Steven I marked the line in the code: it's `*d = *s`. As I said I encounter the violation only on a specific rect, the rects before that, are copied successfully. How can I memset from `src_buffer_i` to `dest_buffer`?

Comment: @Steven Tried to memset every byte of the pixels, still same violation, on the same rect...

Comment: If you write 0xff to *d you get the exception? It's an exception from writing, or is it the read from *s? Are you sure row_spans are multiple of 4? What are the values of src_rect.y and dest_rect.y - are they non-zero?

Comment: Are you checkign return code of locking the texture? Maybe it is failing?

Comment: Could your custom rect conversion function be making invalid rectangles?

Comment: @Steven Writing exception.Row_spans are in bytes, texture bytesperpixel is 4.Src_rect x and y could be non-zero. Going to try checking lock. My rect Conversion function generates correct rects. Because previous executions run successfully...

Comment: @Steven Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34655/discussion-between-xriuk-and-steven).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SDL Wiki [SDL_LockTexture function](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_LockTexture):

> **pixels:** this is filled in with a pointer to the locked pixels, **appropriately offset by the locked area**

So based on this I imagined that I was given a block of pixels padded by the rect's X and Y coordinates so to get to the first pixel I needed to manually get to it, like I tried to do:

```
Uint32* d = dest_buffer + dest_rect.y*dest_row_span + dest_rect.x;
```

And I was getting **access violation on writing**, on **the only rect** where the sum of *X coordinate* and *WIDTH* was lower than the *pitch*, so I started realizing that for some reason I was going out of bounds in that specific rect.
Then I tried to use [SDL_UpdateTexture](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_UpdateTexture) and everything worked flawlessly! So I started inspecting SDL's source code and came near the `SDL_LockTexture` function, particularly when the pixels parameter is set as follows:

```
*pixels =
        (void *) ((Uint8 *) surface->pixels + rect->y * surface->pitch +
                  rect->x * surface->format->BytesPerPixel);
```

So, indeed `pixels` points already to the **beginning of the locked pixels**!!!
And my function becomes this:

```
void XGE_AwsSurface::Paint(unsigned char* src_buffer, int src_row_span, const aws::Rect &src_rect, const aws::Rect &dest_rect){
    Uint32* src_buffer_i = (Uint32*)src_buffer;
    src_row_span /= 4;
    int dest_row_span;
    Uint32* dest_buffer;
    SDL_Rect dst_rect = XGE_AwsRectToSDL(dest_rect);
    SDL_LockTexture(texture, &dst_rect, (void**)&dest_buffer, &dest_row_span);
    dest_row_span /= 4;
    Uint32* s = src_buffer_i + src_rect.y*src_row_span + src_rect.x;
    Uint32* d = dest_buffer;
    for(int y = 0; y < dst_rect.h; y++){
        for(int x = 0; x < dst_rect.w; x++){
            *d = *s;
            d++;
            s++;
        }
        d += dest_row_span - dst_rect.w;
        s += src_row_span - src_rect.width;
    }
    SDL_UnlockTexture(texture);
}
```

I hope this helps someone in trouble...

Comment: So wait, surprise surprise, SDL does what the docs say?

Comment: Doesn't "appropriately offset by the locked area" mean to you that pixels have non zero origin?

Comment: No, it means that the pixel at (0, 0) in the array corresponds to the pixel in the texture at (rect.x, rect.y).

Answer (score 2):

I didn't go with the way of implementing a custom Awesomium class for this. Instead I just updated data of a single texture by querying the surface from Awesomium.

```
// Gets the surface of the web view.
Awesomium::BitmapSurface* surface = static_cast<Awesomium::BitmapSurface*>(webView->surface());
if (surface != NULL)
{
    unsigned char* pixels = nullptr;
    int pitch = 0;

    // "pixels" now point to the pixels of the texture.
    if (SDL_LockTexture(texture, nullptr, (void**)&pixels, &pitch) != 0)
    {
        std::cout << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    }
    // Copies the pixels to the texture.
    surface->CopyTo(pixels, pitch, 4, true, false);
    SDL_UnlockTexture(texture);
}
```

This assumes that you already have created an `SDL_Texture` called `texture`with the correct viewport size. Awesomium then offers an utility method `CopyTo` that you can use to put the pixel data to the texture.

You're right on the fact that the texture needs to be created with the `SDL_PIXELFORMAT_ABGR8888` flag. I also used the `SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING` flag on the texture.

Anyways I find that this approach is somewhat cleaner atleast for someone who's not familiar with Awesomium's class design, as it's mostly using SDL calls and then just a simple call to an Awesomium method.

After that you're just free to render your texture to the screen.

Oh, and if you would like to use the Awesomium custom class structure, I'm sure you can figure out how to adapt this example code to put into use there.

Comment: This would mean writing the entire texture everytime... Please see my edit to the question.

Comment: Is writing the entire texture a performance issue that you have tested out and found out to be an issue? It's better to only optimize when necessary.

Comment: No, but by implementing a class I can use Awesomium events, this way it will paint only when needed and what needed.